# Redirect user to a self-made 404 page when users input wrong arguments

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using Codeigniter version 3.0.6 and now I have a controller named `modifyfiles`. The index function of this controller accepts an argument.

Using the given argument, the index controller will search a desired data in a model. The following code is my index function :

```
public function index($id){

    $_SESSION['logged_in']['idmod'] = $id;
    $this->data['modullist']        = $this->__getmodulbyid($id);
    $this->data['lecturelist']      = $this->__getlecturelist();

    if(count($this->data['modullist']) <= 0){
        show_404();         
    } else {
        $this->load->view($this->layout, $this->data);
    }
}
```

It works very well for now, when I try to insert wrong number arguments it directs me to the codeigniter built-in 404 page.

But when I try to insert some non numbers arguments, say some characters, it directs me to my own 404 page.

Here's my routing rules :

```
$route['404_override']              = 'home/pagemissing';
$route['dosen/modifymodul']         = 'dosen-tools/modifymodul';
$route['dosen/modifymodul/(:num)']  = 'dosen-tools/modifymodul/index/$1';
```

I want when users input wrong arguments, no matter they were numbers or characters, the function will redirect to my own 404 page, not the built-in one. How can I achieve that?

I'm pretty sure the problem is in my conditional block

```
if(count($this->data['modullist']) <= 0){
        show_404();         
} else {
        $this->load->view($this->layout, $this->data);
}
```

What should I write to replace the show_404() ?

Or if I'm not wrong, how can I replace the show_404() with an 404_override trigger?

---

Solved

I did a little research and ended up creating this callback in one of my routing rules

```
$route['dosen/modifymodul/(:num)'] =  

function ($id){
   if(is_numeric($id)){
     return 'dosen-tools/modifymodul/index/'.$id;   
   } else {
     return 'home/pagemissing';
   }
};
```

Thanks everybody

Comment: yes I did. The problem now how to change the show_404() function in my conditional block to something that triggers 404_override in route.php ?

Comment: header('Location:.......'); exit; or require_once ?????

Comment: i'm not quite sure - why would you do that ? a wrong user input isn't a 404, i would load my own view for this matter